# Kafka consumers all have assigned_partition set to 0 but at runtime are assigned differnt partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I am not sure if i am doing something wrong - but if someone can please help shed some light on this.

**Scenario:**

- Launching a broker having 1 topic with two partitions.
- Launching 2 consumers - with two separate client_id and both
  registering to the same consumer group and listening to the same
  topic (above).

Before i fire up the producer - i wanted to see what partitions these consumers are assigned to and see :

```
Listening on Topic : TOPIC_2PART
Status :True
ClientId : consumer_3_1
***************
  CONFIG 
***************
bootstrap_servers -> $node1_port
client_id -> consumer_3_1
group_id -> CGRP_TOPIC_2PART
value_deserializer -> <function CreateConsumer.consume.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000020175217DC8>
partition_assignment_strategy -> (<class 'kafka.coordinator.assignors.range.RangePartitionAssignor'>, <class 'kafka.coordinator.assignors.roundrobin.RoundRobinPartitionAssignor'>)
metric_group_prefix -> consumer
***************
  METRICS 
***************         
    consumer-fetch-manager-metrics
    **assigned-partitions->0.0**
```

And for the second consumer :

```
Listening on Topic : TOPIC_2PART
Status :True
ClientId : consumer_3
***************
  CONFIG 
***************
bootstrap_servers -> $node1_port
client_id -> consumer_3
group_id -> CGRP_TOPIC_2PART
value_deserializer -> <function CreateConsumer.consume.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000118DC956DC8>
partition_assignment_strategy -> (<class 'kafka.coordinator.assignors.range.RangePartitionAssignor'>, <class 'kafka.coordinator.assignors.roundrobin.RoundRobinPartitionAssignor'>)
selector -> <class 'selectors.SelectSelector'>
***************
  METRICS 
***************
            kafka-metrics-count
            consumer-fetch-manager-metrics
            consumer-coordinator-metrics
    assigned-partitions->0.0
```

So above before either consumer starts consume assigned-partitions are 0

After producer starts sending messages to both partitions on the topic - i see one consumer having partition 0 and the other partition 1

```
ConsumerRecord(topic='TOPIC_2PART', **partition=0**, offset=14, timestamp=1616346804116, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value={xxxx}, headers=[], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=-1, serialized_value_size=99, serialized_header_size=-1)
```

And the second consumer having

```
ConsumerRecord(topic='TOPIC_2PART', **partition=1**, offset=4, timestamp=1616346723367, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value={}, headers=[], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=-1, serialized_value_size=83, serialized_header_size=-1)
ConsumerRecord(topic='TOPIC_2PART', **partition=1**, offset=5, timestamp=1616346743556, timestamp_type=0, key=None, value={}, headers=[], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=-1, serialized_value_size=94, serialized_header_size=-1)
```

My question is why am i seeing the assigned-partition on both consumers set to 0 ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `assigned-partitions` metric is the [number of partitions assigned](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html#consumer-group-metrics) to each consumer, not the partitions ids.
With two consumers and two partitions, this should be set to 1 for each of them once you subscribe. So question is - when does subscription occur? Seems like the information you've pasted was extracted before the subscription.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding .
I wrote a class to call KafkaConsumer and from console i am extantiating an object to this class by passing the broker hosts / topic and returning to the object a tuple of consumer messages / config and metrics.  So b4 i call yield to parse thru the messages i am printing out the metrics.  
But then i would assume that the partitions are assigned when i create the object not at printing the messages ?

Comment: Lior btw I changed my script to create a new object and print metrics - seems like when the object is created for some reason the default partition is always 0.0 and after u initialize the object and u start consuming the data is still 0.0 - but the messages have the correct partition assigned.

Comment: Neale, perhaps you could post your code here, will be easier to relate to it.

Comment: ofc Thank you again posting in the min thread - there is no <code> block in comments.